# Is the square of a square root always non-negative? ($\sqrt{x}^2 = |x|?$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, radicals, absolute-value

I know that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|.$

But does $\sqrt{x}^2 = |x|?$

It seems like it should, since
$$\sqrt{x}^2 = \sqrt{x} \cdot \sqrt{x}$$
and $\sqrt{x}$ is non-negative, so their product should be non-negative.

But I haven't seen a rule like this, so I'm guessing it isn't the case, and am just wondering why.

Comment: It is a convention that $\sqrt{x}$ denotes the non-negatvie number $y$ with $y^2=x$

Comment: Think $(\sqrt{-7})^2=-7$.

Comment: What if x = -1?

Comment: For non-negative $x$, you have $(\sqrt{x})^2=x$, if $x$ is negative, you need complex numbers to define $\sqrt{x}$

Comment: If we have defined $\sqrt x$ with complex numbers, then it is not true in general that either $\sqrt{x^2}$ or $(\sqrt x)^2$ will be equal to $|x|.$ So I think we are supposed to use real numbers only. But if we _did_ allow complex numbers, then $(\sqrt x)^2=x$ for all $x,$ at least if $\sqrt\cdot$ means principal square root (i.e. it produces a number and not a solution set).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming we're dealing with real numbers only here (no complex numbers). Then the statement $\sqrt{x}^2=|x|$ is true… but we don't need a "rule" like this because we can do even better. The expression $\sqrt{x}$ is well-defined over the real numbers only if $x\ge0$, and therefore $\sqrt{x}^2=x$ — we don't need the absolute value here because $x$ is already non-negative.

**EDIT:** In other words, the property $\sqrt{x}^2=x$ is true whenever both sides (especially the left-hand side) are well-defined. But it's not true otherwise; in particular, it does not apply when $x$ is negative. And using the absolute value on the right-hand side wouldn't help with that.

Comment: So what happens if $x$ is negative, then?

Comment: In the realm of real numbers -- nothing. The left-hand side is undefined, so the whole statement doesn't make sense. In other words, you cannot apply it when $x$ is negative.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=(\sqrt x)^2$ is not the same function that $g(x)=|x|$.

Both have the same rank $[0,+\infty[$ but its domains are distinct: $f$ has domain the non-negative numbers while $g$ has all the real as domain.